# Implement floating action button bottom_right of listview - Xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview that binds an image & text. I have been trying to add a floating button bottom-right of this page but to no avail. Done some research but there seems to still be no clear solution for this. Anyone who knows how i can implement this? In my xaml code , I have shown what I have tried.

My xaml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.Page1"
                 Title="Stores">
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

            <ToolbarItem Text="About" 
                         Icon="ic_action_more_vert.png"
                         Priority="0"
                         Order="Secondary"
                         Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>

            <ToolbarItem Text="Settings"
                         Icon="ic_action_more_vert.png"
                         Priority="0"
                         Order="Secondary"/>

        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


        <ListView x:Name="MainListView" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="MainListView_ItemTapped" SeparatorColor="DarkGray">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding Image}" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" />


                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

***//here is what I attempted but the image just covers the whole page***
        <Image Source="add.png"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HeightRequest="0"
               WidthRequest="0"
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,.99, 65, 65"
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" >
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                  Command="{Binding clickNewCard}"
                  CommandParameter="3" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

    </ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of problems here:

1. If you are setting the Content of the `ContentPage`, you must declare
   **only one element** (so you should use a layout container like a `StackLayout` - that can handle multiple children - to compose your page). See [this topic](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/pages/) about it;
2. You're setting the `AbsoluteLayout`'s attached properties, but **your image is not inside an `AbsoluteLayout`**. [This topic](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout/) leads the way for use `AbsoluteLayout` (I guess it's NOT what you need here).
3. You're setting  `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` and `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` to the image view, when actually this properties should be on `ListView`. [This topic](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options/) is about the `LayoutOptions`.

Try this way and tell me if it works fine for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.Page1"
             Title="Stores">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="About" 
                     Icon="ic_action_more_vert.png"
                     Priority="0"
                     Order="Secondary"
                     Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Settings"
                     Icon="ic_action_more_vert.png"
                     Priority="0"
                     Order="Secondary"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <Grid>
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                  x:Name="MainListView" 
                  HasUnevenRows="True" 
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  ItemTapped="MainListView_ItemTapped" 
                  SeparatorColor="DarkGray">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding Image}" 
                               Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               TextColor="Black" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
               Source="add.png"
               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
               Margin="0,0,30,30"
               HeightRequest="0"
               WidthRequest="0" >
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                  Command="{Binding clickNewCard}"
                  CommandParameter="3" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, this worked for me! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Not at all! I'm here to help  =). I would glad if you accept the answer, then